# How to split Serilog log file into multiple files?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm trying to split logs by SourceContext.
After spending some days and reading the documentation and many, many, many posts, I have this config and not a solution:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Debug", "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "Logs/log-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Logger",
      "Args": {
        "confgureLogger": {
          "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "Logs/log-HTTP-.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Namespace} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Filter": [
            {
              "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
              "Args": {
                "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.AspNetCore')"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Logger",
      "Args": {
        "confgureLogger": {
          "WriteTo": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "path": "Logs/log-API-.txt",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Namespace} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Filter": [
            {
              "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
              "Args": {
                "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'My.Application')"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "Name": "Console",
      "Args": {
        "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {NameSpace} - {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried with "subLogs" and with multiple root logs.

With sublogs I have only one file.
With rootlogs I have the same log in both files.
I no longer know what to do other than change the logger and switch to NLog.

Is there a working solution?

Comment: can you better explain what your trying to do? and are you saying that this config is not working? or its not what you want?